# lambda functors assignment workaround

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there something wrong with the code below?

```
#include <iostream>

#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
void assign_lambda(T&& f)
{
  typedef typename std::remove_reference<T>::type functor_type;

  typedef typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(functor_type),
    std::alignment_of<functor_type>::value>::type buffer_type;

  static char store[sizeof(buffer_type)];

  auto const p(new (store) functor_type(std::forward<T>(f)));

  (*p)();
}

int main()
{
  for (int i(0); i != 5; ++i)
  {
    assign_lambda([i](){ std::cout << i << std::endl; });
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I worry though that this might be non-standard and/or dangerous to do.

EDIT:
Why initialize into a `char` array you ask? One might allocate a block of size `sizeof(buffer_type)` from the heap and reuse for repeated assignments (i.e. avoid repeated memory allocations), if the block should prove large enough.

> void*operator new(std::size_t size);
>
> Effects: The allocation function (3.7.4.1) called by a new-expression (5.3.4) to allocate size bytes of storage suitably aligned to represent any object of that size.

I suppose if I allocate from the heap the alignment issues will go away.

Comment: it won't work well in multithreaded environment

Comment: @bobah Nothing a mutex couldn't fix.

Comment: what's wrong with `std::function`?

Comment: Once you fix the alignment as described below, this particular code works. However, if your lambda captures anything that needs a destructor, you're not calling it, so you'll get leaks.

Comment: @sehe I want to avoid the repeated memory allocations, that happen with assignments.

Comment: @user1095108 assignment is not really more expensive than destruction and copy-construction - and what memory allocations are you talking about?

Comment: @ArneMertz `std::function` needs to use a `boost::any` type erasure technique to store lambdas, which means allocations from the heap.

Comment: @user1095108 you don't need a `std::function`. Just store a static `functor_type` instead of placment-new'ing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to make sure that `store` has the proper alignment for `functor_type`. Apart from that, I don't see any problems regarding standard conformance. However, you can easily address the multithreading issue by making the array nonstatic, because `sizeof` gives a compiletime constant.

The alignment is demanded by **§5.3.4,14**:

> [ Note: when the allocation function returns a value other than null, it must be a pointer to a block of storage in which space for the object has been reserved. The block of storage is assumed to be appropriately aligned and of the requested size. [...] -end note ]

There is another paragraph, §3.7.4.1 about alignment, but that one does explicitly not apply to placement new (§18.6.1.3,1).

To get the alignment right, you can do the following:

```
template <typename T>
void assign_lambda(T&& f)
{
  typedef typename std::remove_reference<T>::type functor_type;

  //alignas(functor_type) char store[sizeof(functor_type)];
  std::aligned_storage<sizeof(functor_type), 
            std::alignment_of<functor_type>::value>::type store;

  auto const p(new (&store) functor_type(std::forward<T>(f)));

  (*p)();

  //"placement delete"
  p->~functor_type();
}
```

**Update:**
The approach shown above is not different from using just a normal variable:

```
template <typename T>
void assign_lambda(T&& f)
{
  typedef typename std::remove_reference<T>::type functor_type;

  functor_type func{std::forward<T>(f)};

  func();
}
```

If it *has* to be a static variable inside the function you will need an RAII wrapper for functors that are not assignable. Just placement-newing is not sufficient since the functors will not get destroyed properly and ressources they possess (e.g. via captured smartpointers) will not get released.

```
template <typename F>
struct RAIIFunctor {
  typedef typename std::remove_reference<F>::type functor_type;

  std::aligned_storage<sizeof(functor_type), 
            std::alignment_of<functor_type>::value>::type store;

  functor_type* f;

  RAIIFunctor() : f{nullptr} {}
  ~RAIIFunctor() { destroy(); }

  template <class T>
  void assign(T&& t) {
    destroy();
    f = new(&store) functor_type {std::forward<T>(t)};
  }

  void destroy() {
    if (f) 
      f->~functor_type();
    f = nullptr;
  }

  void operator() {
    (*f)();
  }
};


template <typename T>
void assign_lambda(T&& f)
{
  static RAIIFunctor<T> func;

  func.assign(std::forward<T>(f));
  func();
}
```

You can see the code in action [here](http://ideone.com/3N2PVe)

Comment: What happens if it doesn't have proper alignment? Can you please give quotes from the standard?

Comment: If you don't provide proper alignment, then the behaviour is undefined. In practice it ranges from "works as intended if a bit slower" on x86 to "bus error" on other architectures.

Comment: @user1095108 most likely... not ok. If you have to ask: **certainly not**.

Comment: Because alignment, casts, placement new, etc. are all pretty advanced language features. You'd best not need to ask the question. More specifically, what @R.MartinhoFernandes said...

Comment: @user1095108 fixed that one.

Answer (score 3):

I don't get it. Why would one use `aligned_storage` merely to get some size to create uninitialised storage, instead of... using the aligned storage it provides? It's almost like travelling from Berlin to Lisbon by taking a Berlin -> Lisbon flight followed by a Lisbon -> Moscow flight.

```
  typedef typename std::remove_reference<T>::type functor_type;

  typedef typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(functor_type),
    std::alignment_of<functor_type>::value>::type buffer_type;

  static buffer_type store;

  auto const p(new (&store) functor_type(std::forward<T>(f)));
```

Comment: thanks for pointing me to `aligned_storage` - did only know about `alignof` and `alignas` until now.

Comment: My understanding of placement `new` was such, that `new` might not return a pointer to the start of the given block, but possibly move forward a little to satisfy the alignment requirements, hence you sometimes need more storage than the size of the object you allocate. Further, my prime concern was whether my code was OK, standard compliant. Yours would work too, I understand, but is my code, such as it is, also OK?

Comment: No, placement new has no effect on the pointer (and therefore your code didn't guarantee the alignment requirements were fulfilled).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the alignment issue already mentioned, you are creating a copy of the lambda through placement `new` but you are not destroying the copy.

The following code illustrates the problem:

```
// This class plays the role of the OP's lambdas
struct Probe {
    Probe() { std::cout << "Ctr" << '\n'; }
    Probe(const Probe&) { std::cout << "Cpy-ctr" << '\n'; }
    ~Probe() { std::cout << "Dtr" << '\n'; }

};

// This plays the role of the OP's assign_lambda
void f(const Probe& p) {

    typedef typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(Probe),
        std::alignment_of<Probe>::value>::type buffer_type;

    static buffer_type store;
    new (&store) Probe(p);
}

int main() {

    Probe p;

    // This plays the role of the loop
    f(p);
    f(p);
    f(p);
}
```

The output is:

```
Ctr
Cpy-ctr
Cpy-ctr
Cpy-ctr
Dtr
```

Therefore, 4 objects are constructed and only one is destroyed.

In addition, in the OP's code the `store` is `static` and this means that one lambda is repeatedly constructed on top of the other as if the latter was just raw memory.

Comment: `static` objects have the lifetime of the application, the destructor of a static lambda is called only once as well. I am here trying to copy a lambda into a static "lambda".

Comment: @user1095108: You are not assigning a lambda `b` to a lambda `a`. You are using the memory occupied by `a` as if it was raw memory and creating a copy of `b` on it. The object `a` is not properly destroyed. Basically you are trying to create two different objects into the same memory address and (sonce one is not a sub-object of the other) this is not allowed.

Comment: Could one not solve this issue with a custom deleter to call before each assignment?

Comment: @user1095108 that would still not destroy the last assigned functor. If the lambda captures some RAII object by value, the resource would not be freed appropiately.

Comment: @user1095108 I updated my answer to store one static, RAII-managed functor in `assign_lambda`

Comment: @ArneMertz Your class can only hold one type of functor, while I am trying to do a kind of type erasure (i.e. a `std::function` kind of container of functors), while trying to avoid allocations (a problem with `std::function`), reusing old memory space. Here's code: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14730/impossibly-fast-delegate-in-c11

Comment: @user1095108 well, your question did not state that intent. You only asked if that code you posted had problems, and my answer tries to fix them, nothing more. In fact, you were defining a template function that gets newly instantiaded for each different type you call it with, meaning it gives a new static storage array for each type you call it with. And since lambda expressions give unique closure types you will have a new instantiation and a new storage block for each lambda you call it with. That's exactly what my class does. If you want a solution for a given problem, then ask for it.

Comment: @ArneMertz Your comments did come handy when implementing the functor container, where I am realigning the pointers now. Thanks!